# Celery/Rabbitmq/Django - Old tasks being executed without being called in my code

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery

I have a simple shared celery task like this:

```
@shared_task
def add():
    x = barakah(name="add()", year="add()", month="add()")
    x.save()
    return "id is add()= " + str(x.id)
```

And I call it here in this CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE:

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'add': {
        'task': 'water.tasks.add',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=3),
        'args': ()
    },
}
```

This is the celery command I use:

```
celery -A adi worker -B -l info
```

It runs fine as per schedule but other old tasks are also executing as well.  How do I stop the old tasks?  I have even tried uninstalling celery and rabbitmq but the old tasks seem to be cached somewhere.  I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22103401/django-rabbitmq-celery-why-does-celery-run-old-versions-of-my-tasks-after) but what I tried didn't work.  Any ideas?

Comment: Might this be of any help?

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230833/stopping-purging-periodic-tasks-in-django-celery][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230833/stopping-purging-periodic-tasks-in-django-celery

Answer (score 0):

Use `celery purge` command.

From celery docs:

> purge: Purge messages from all configured task queues.
>
> Warning There is no undo for this operation, and messages will be
>   permanently deleted!

```
$ celery -A proj purge
```